# Upload data file and run source.R in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to run my `shinyapp.R` (includes `ui` and `server`) using `source("model.R")`. I want to let a user upload a data file and run `model.R`  in my `shinyapp.R`.

How should I let `model.R` run using user uploaded data set. It does not read the dataset I uploaded from the shiny app.

My code:

```
source("model.R")

server <- function(input, output){
                   dataset <- reactive({
                                        infile  <- input$datafile
                                        if( is.null(infile) ) {
                                              return(NULL)
                                        } else { 
                                              as.data.frame(read.csv(infile$datapath, header=TRUE))      
                                        } 
                                        })    

                  output$plot <- renderPlot({pred_plot})
                  })

ui <- fluidPage(fileInput("datafile", "Choose data file", accept = c('text/csv','.csv','.xlsx') ),    
                 mainPanel(plotOutput("plot") 
                )

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

I get the following error message:

`Error in eval(ei, envir) : object 'dataset' not found`

Comment: did you just `code` line every line one by one?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out, I save necessary functions as R objects and call it in shiny app. That way, you can render things as needed.